# Rails sort child model based on parent model distance calculation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sorting, geokit

I have a `product` model and a `shop` model. The relationship between two is shop `has_many` products and products `belongs_to` shop.

The shop model has two fields `longitude` and `latitude` used for distance calculation using [geokit-rails](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails). I have been successful in sorting shops by nearest distance to any given longitude and latitude using:

```
Shop.by_distance(origin:[params[:latitude], params[:longitude]]).sort_by{|s| s.distance_to([params[:latitude], params[:longitude]])}
```

The problem is with products. The products needs to be sorted according to nearest shop location as well. I have searched through and found out that a child model can be sorted from parents attributes like this:

```
Product.joins(:shop).order('shops.name')
```

The order function works only if supplied with model field. How can I sort products calculating shop distance.

Please help.

Comment: `.by_distance` will allready apply an order clause and sort the records by distance from the origin. Tacking `.sort_by` which iterates through the results as an array onto it does not accomplish anything - you're literally just doing the same thing twice.

Comment: Thank you for finding out. I will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation on [using `:through`](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails#using-through) - this should be exactly what you need.

So `Product` would look like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  acts_as_mappable through: :shop
  ...
end
```

And your query would be something like:

```
Product.joins(:shop).by_distance(origin: [params[:latitude], params[:longitude]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already can filter and sort the Shop

```
@shops = Shop.by_distance(origin:[params[:latitude], params[:longitude]]).sort_by{|s| s.distance_to([params[:latitude], params[:longitude]])}
```

This will get all products from each shops according to the distance:

```
@closest_products = @shops.map(&:products)
```

If you want to weed out duplicate products, use this instead:

```
@closest_products = @shops.map(&:children).flatten.uniq
```

You may try an alternative method (I have not tested this):

```
@closest_products = Product.where(shop: @shops)
```

Comment: The goal here is to first get products, it may possibly be filtered and then sort them with respect to their shops.
Trying out second line resulted in: 
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `associations' for #<ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer:0x007f9347f0f398>>